# How to get one data from get request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to get only one data from my get request, for example `firstName` using `data` from my code below?

this is my code:

```
  getUsername() async{
    var id = sharedPreferences.getInt('id');
    var response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:80/user/$id');
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      return data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u got first name parameter in your response then u can use :

```
data['first name'] or data['parameter name']
```

that will give u value of any parameter